# leaflet tiles with protomaps pmtiles are not visibles (seems to be transparent)

Tags: vector, leaflet, osm.pbf

i'm using our own pmtiles tileset server, the test url is : https://tilesets.urbanease.io/cadastre/64/64102/without_protobuf.pmtiles
the location for seeing it is :bayonne, france latlng=[43.492949,-1.474841]

on the viewer, all seems to be ok bit leaflet preview don't work [viewer](https://protomaps.github.io/PMTiles/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftilesets.urbanease.io%2Fcadastre%2F64%2F64102%2Fwithout_protobuf.pmtiles)

i'm using react and leaflet with the npm protomaps package version 1.19.0

my code is simple

```
const map = useMap();
const url =
  'https://tilesets.urbanease.io/cadastre/64/64102/without_protobuf.pmtiles';
const layer = protomaps.leafletLayer({
     url: url,
     id: 'cadastral',
});
layer.addTo(map);
```

canvas are created but seems to be transparent, colors in paint_rules layer are good and opacity ok

i don't understand where is the pb bad pmtiles file? no compatibility with leaflet?
thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was our custom layer name who don't mach to default paint_rules of protomaps package,
with custom paint_rules it works fine